# How to say "Let me take my breath please" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

I just wanna know how to say "Let me take my breath please", in case of "I have just arrived and so tiered".

Thank you...

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Unfortunately, your translation question is [off-topic](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) according to our rules. Please [edit] in your attempt to hightligh the specific issue you’re interested about, or it will get closed. Learn more about closing, on-topicness and editing in the [help].

Comment: What did you come up with? What is still unclear?

Comment: I have never heard "let me TAKE my breath". Did you mean "let me CATCH my breath"? There is, of course, "taking ones breath away" when something is "breathtaking", which has quite a different meaning.

Comment: @Marakai , Yes exactly that's what I want to know "let me catch my breath", sorry for the bad writing. I am forgetting my English because of German :( , since English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx51eegLTY8 :-D

Answer (score 3):

How about

> Lass mich erstmal zu Atem kommen.

Or, though it would be more common with pauses/breaks, not necessarily the arrival itself:

> Lass mich kurz verschnaufen.

Both point out the *out-of-breath*-state and the need for a break.

Answer (score 2):

An usual phrase is:

> Lass mich erst mal ankommen.

It means something like *let me arrive first* (imperative singular). It's metaphoric, but every German speaker will understand. You will usually say it when you just arrived at your final target and you want to sit down before you do anything else.